# UITableViewCell AFNetworking load image with animation only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

When first time load image (via URL), the image loading should be animated. After that, scrolling the tableview should not trigger the animation.

The code below has problem: animation is triggered whenever UITableViewCell is dequeue, causing image dissolving from the dequeued cell. How to allow animation to be triggered only once?

```
[thumbnail cancelImageRequestOperation];
NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
if (imageUrl) {
    [thumbnail setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl]
                     placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                              success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                      [UIView transitionWithView:thumbnail
                                                        duration:0.5f
                                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                      animations:^{thumbnail.image = image;}
                                                      completion:nil];

                              }
                              failure:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store images as property of your datasource or you should store images on disk.

you have to store image as property after completion of your request.

```
if(!obj.image)
NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
if (imageUrl) {
[thumbnail setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl]
                 placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                  [UIView transitionWithView:thumbnail
                                                    duration:0.5f
                                                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                  animations:^{thumbnail.image = image;}
                                                  completion:{
obj.image = image;
cell.image = obj.image;
}];

                          }
                          failure:nil];
}
}
else
{
    cell.image = obj.image;
}
```

For save into disk you have to do same just need to check if that images is exist at disk then set it from disk either call for download.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never checking if the image has already been downloaded for that particular row.

Whenever you download your images, you need to save them somewhere (like an `NSMutableArray`) in your `success` block. Before you call `setImageWithURLRequest`, check your array to see if an image already exists for that row. If so, load it locally. If not, only *then* call `setImageWithURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [UIImageView+AFNetworking.h](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h), it explicitly states that in the success block called by `-setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`:

> If the image was returned from cache, the request and response
>   parameters will be `nil`.

You could use this fact to run the animation only when the request and response parameters are non-nil.

As an aside, `-setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` actually *sets* the image. I'm not sure you need to do it again in your animation block.

Comment: Thanks. The description also says: If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block to set the image of the image view before returning. If no success block is specified, the default behavior of setting the image with `self.image = image` is applied.